# NSArray - quick way to find index of object for know description

Tags: iphone, cocoa

Hi i have NSArray of id objects.
And i know object description NSString.
how can i find object and avoid array enumeration?
p.s. i don't like to using NSDictionary, bcs it's do code more difficult

Comment: Try to learn things the right way from the very beginning and spare yourself the need to later on unlearn your wrong/inferior method. That being said use a dictionary if you need to store and retrieve objects by a given key. Using `[dict setObject:object forKey:@"key"]` and `[dict objectForKey:@"key"]` will not only be easier to grasp than filtering an array with a predicate, it will also be much faster and usually the better way to do it.

Comment: @Regexident : I dont know whats his requirement I answered predicate will solve ur problem, but he needs something else... kindly check my answer with comments.

Comment: Further more an object description's purpose is not to be used as a key/predicate of any kind. Its main purpose is debugging/logging. Everything else (usually) indicates some kind of [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: While your answer might solve OP's problem it doesn't change the fact that OP is clearly barking up the wrong tree. One can show him how to do it (what OP's wrongly trying to do) a little less wrong or how to do it right. I'd always go for the latter.

Comment: @Regexident : Yes I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a lookup you plan to perform more often and speed is an issue, you should probably not store the objects in a NSArray but instead in a NSDictionary to begin with, where the keys are the description strings of the objects and the values are the objects themselves. You can then use `objectForKey:` with the description string as argument, which is a O(1) lookup.

Comment: my reason to avoid dictionaries, bcs i need to more clear code

Comment: @user170317: Dictionaries result in cleaner code. That's why they were invented. Abstraction. We could abolish complex data structures all together and do all programming with plain lists. But pretty quickly one couldn't see the forest for the trees. Use dicts when you need dicts (store & retrieve objects by key), sets when you need sets (store unique objects) and arrays when you need arrays (order objects).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
[myArray containsObject:yourObject];
```

Or you can filter it :

```
[myArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: please read carefully, i don't have object i have description string only. please specify predicate

Comment: Object description ??? NSLog(@"%@",[myObject description]); prints the object...  are you referring to this description?

Comment: yep, i have ,[myObject description] saved in another place and i like to find by that description object inside array

Comment: Please post your array structure... because i am feeling my both answer will work with little bit of change... but i need to check and customize.

Comment: @user170317: If you're using object descriptions as some kind of identifiers (and are even saving them to disk o.O) then you're clearly on the wrong track. The learning curves of huge frameworks such as Cocoa are steep, no doubt, but do your future self a favour and avoid learning easy (but obviously bad) hacks (just what your abuse of `description` is guilty of). In the long run you'll learn quicker and be a better programmer.

Comment: @Regexident i like to be better programmer with your help. please explain in your answer more quick and clear way, where i array will filled not dictionaries, but just objects, and how i can find necessary object inside. in other way your words just words...

Comment: @user170317: simply used [myDict objectForKey:yourKey];